# Java XSLT combine two inputs xml

Tags: java, xslt

I want to combine two input xml string into one output using XSLT and Java, here is my code. I don't know why it doesn't work. how to fix it ?

Thanks.

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Test {

    final static String sourceXml1 ="<languages-list>\r\n" + 
            "<language>\r\n" + 
            "<family>John Family</family>\r\n" + 
            "<users>asfasd</users>\r\n" +
            "</language>\r\n" + 
            "</languages-list>";

    final static String sourceXml2 = "<languages-list>\r\n" + 
            "<language>\r\n" + 
            "<name>John</name>\r\n" + 
            "<region>NYC</region>\r\n" + 
            "</language>\r\n" + 
            "</languages-list>";

    final static String xsl =
            "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"2.0\"\r\n" + 
            "xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "<xsl:param name=\"doc1\" />\r\n" + 
            "<xsl:param name=\"doc2\" />\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "    <xsl:template match=\"/\">\r\n" + 
            "        <html>\r\n" + 
            "            <body>\r\n" +      
            "                <table border=\"1\">\r\n" +        
            "        <xsl:for-each select=\"language-list/language\">\r\n" + 
            "                    <tr>\r\n" +        
            "                        <td><xsl:value-of select=\"$doc1/family\"/></td>\r\n" + 
            "                        <td><xsl:value-of select=\"$doc1/users\"/></td>\r\n" + 
            "                        <td><xsl:value-of select=\"$doc2/name\"/></td>\r\n" + 
            "                        <td><xsl:value-of select=\"$doc2/region\"/></td>\r\n" + 
            "                    </tr>\r\n" + 
            "                 </xsl:for-each>\r\n" + 
            "                </table>\r\n" + 
            "            </body>\r\n" + 
            "        </html>\r\n" + 
            "    </xsl:template>\r\n" + 
            "</xsl:stylesheet> ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sourceXml1 + "\n=======\n" + sourceXml2+"\n=======\n"+xsl);

        try {

            StreamSource stream1 = new StreamSource(new StringReader(sourceXml1));
            StreamSource stream2 = new StreamSource(new StringReader(sourceXml2));      

            StringReader xslReader = new StringReader(xsl);

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslReader)); // style sheet

            transformer.setParameter("doc1", stream1);  
            transformer.setParameter("doc2", stream2);  

            transformer.transform(stream1, new StreamResult(writer));

            String result = writer.toString();
            System.out.println("==============\n"+result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show us the result you want and the one you get.

Comment: Is there any reason why you would prefer not to use the `document()` function in XSLT to load the files you wish to merge (assuming that in your real scenario those two input documents are files)? You could pass the file *names* as parameters.

Comment: data will be retrieved from database table, so there are no external files

Comment: @Martin output should contain data from two input xml string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to process each stream only once so use one main input document and one parameter, then, assuming your XSLT processor supports parameters of type source (like Saxon 9 does), use

```
import java.io.StringReader;
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Test2014062001 {

    final static String sourceXml1 ="<languages-list>\r\n" + 
            "<language>\r\n" + 
            "<family>John Family</family>\r\n" + 
            "<users>asfasd</users>\r\n" +
            "</language>\r\n" + 
            "</languages-list>";

    final static String sourceXml2 = "<languages-list>\r\n" + 
            "<language>\r\n" + 
            "<name>John</name>\r\n" + 
            "<region>NYC</region>\r\n" + 
            "</language>\r\n" + 
            "</languages-list>";

    final static String xsl =
            "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"2.0\"\r\n" + 
            "xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\">\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "<xsl:param name=\"doc2\" />\r\n" + 
            "\r\n" + 
            "    <xsl:template match=\"/\">\r\n" + 
            "        <html>\r\n" + 
            "            <body>\r\n" + 
            "                <div><xsl:value-of select=\"system-property('xsl:vendor')\"/></div>\r\n" +
            "                <table border=\"1\">\r\n" +        
            "        <xsl:for-each select=\"languages-list/language\">\r\n" +
            "          <xsl:variable name=\"pos\" select=\"position()\"/>\r\n" +  
            "                    <tr>\r\n" +        
            "                        <td><xsl:value-of select=\"family\"/></td>\r\n" + 
            "                        <td><xsl:value-of select=\"users\"/></td>\r\n" + 
            "                        <td><xsl:value-of select=\"$doc2/languages-list/language[$pos]/name\"/></td>\r\n" + 
            "                        <td><xsl:value-of select=\"$doc2/languages-list/language[$pos]/region\"/></td>\r\n" + 
            "                    </tr>\r\n" + 
            "                 </xsl:for-each>\r\n" + 
            "                </table>\r\n" + 
            "            </body>\r\n" + 
            "        </html>\r\n" + 
            "    </xsl:template>\r\n" + 
            "</xsl:stylesheet> ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(sourceXml1 + "\n=======\n" + sourceXml2+"\n=======\n"+xsl);

        try {

            StreamSource stream1 = new StreamSource(new StringReader(sourceXml1));
            StreamSource stream2 = new StreamSource(new StringReader(sourceXml2));      

            StringReader xslReader = new StringReader(xsl);

            StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
            TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(xslReader)); // style sheet

            transformer.setParameter("doc2", stream2);  

            transformer.transform(stream1, new StreamResult(writer));

            String result = writer.toString();
            System.out.println("==============\n"+result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Output I get with Saxon 9 is

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div>Saxonica</div>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
            <td>John Family</td>
            <td>asfasd</td>
            <td>John</td>
            <td>NYC</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you get an error, if so, which one? Or don't you get the result you want, which so far you have not described exactly.

Comment: it should show a table, <table border="1"><tr><td>Kannada</td><td>Kannada</td><td>John</td><td>asfasd</td></tr></table>

Comment: Which XSLT processor do you use?

Comment: I have now tested the suggestion made earlier with Java 7 and Saxon 9 HE and found that your original code had a wrong XPath `language-list/language`, after correcting that to `languages-list/language` to match the input samples the code works. It does however not work with the built-in Xalan of Java 7, it does not allow passing in a source as a parameter, it wants a node-set.